# Intent filter para URLs no es reconocido por el telefono

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

Estoy creando una app que necesita aparecer como opción al compartir un link desde Youtube o Youtube Music. Ya intente que con varios filters pero la app nunca apareció como opción para compartir.

Me gustaria aclarar que yo buildeo la app usando "npx expo run:android --variant release" porque Expo Go no te deja probar intents y buildear usando EAS es muy lento.

Despues en el app.js obtengo los datos usando Linking de expo-linking

Mi app.json(acortado):

```json
"android": {
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "SEND",
          "category": [
            "DEFAULT",
            "BROWSABLE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": {
            "scheme": "https",
            "host": "*.youtube.com"
          },
          "category": [
            "DEFAULT",
            "BROWSABLE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "action": "SEND",
          "data": {
            "scheme": "https",
            "host": "*.youtube.com"
          },
          "category": [
            "DEFAULT",
            "BROWSABLE"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.ticua.NearShare"
    }
```

Mi AndroidManifest(acortado):

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="49.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.ticua.NearShare"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.youtube.com"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.youtube.com"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar con este intent filter, añádelo a tu activity que se encargará de recibir el intent:

```
<intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

</intent-filter>
```

[image: Preview proyecto]